# How to create tree table using react js using recursion?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have just started learning React

I am working on solution where i want to create tree like table using react.

So basically functionality is like there is simple table with each row having conditional expand icon, i achieved basic functionality of rendering another row component when i click on row.

Basic solution that i have achieved is whenever user clicks on any i call function expand row add static children under that clicked row array and display it using passing children object to subrow component.

Now i want whenever user clicks on expanded row children, it should expand to next level having displaying data related to second expand.

So basically it will look like

```
- Row 1
  - Child 1
    - Child 1.1
    - Child 1.2
  + Child 2
+ Row 2
```

I have created basic prototype using static json data from jsonplaceholder apis

Here is code

App.js

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import TableRowData from "./TableRowData";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [splits, setSplit] = useState(["campid", "appid", "os"]);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <TableRowData avaliableSplits={splits} />
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

TableRowData.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, Fragment } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import SubRow from "./SubRow";

class TableRowData extends React.Component {
  state = { data: [] };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((res) => {
      this.setState({ data: res.data });
    });
  }
  render() {
    const updateState = (id, itemAttributes) => {
      var index = this.state.data.findIndex((x) => x.id === id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.setState({
          data: [
            ...this.state.data.slice(0, index),
            Object.assign({}, this.state.data[index], itemAttributes),
            ...this.state.data.slice(index + 1)
          ]
        });
      }
    };

    const expandRow = (user) => {
      user.children = [
        { id: "6656", name: "sfsdfds1" },
        { id: "66563", name: "sfsdfds2" }
      ];

      //    this.setState({data:[...this.state.data],})
      updateState(user.id, { isExpanded: true });
    };

    const collapseRow = (user) => {
      user.children = undefined;
      updateState(user.id, { isExpanded: false });
    };

    if (this.state.data) {
      const appData = this.state.data.map((user) => {
        return (
          <Fragment key={user.id}>
            <tr key={user.id}>
              <td>
                {user.isExpanded === true ? (
                  <button type="button" onClick={() => collapseRow(user)}>
                    -
                  </button>
                ) : (
                  <button type="button" onClick={() => expandRow(user)}>
                    +
                  </button>
                )}
                {user.id}
              </td>
              <td>{user.name}</td>
            </tr>
            {!!user.children && <SubRow rowData={user.children} />}
          </Fragment>
        );
      });
      return <Fragment>{appData}</Fragment>;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

export default TableRowData;
```

SubRow.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, Fragment } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const SubRow = (props) => {
    const appData = props.rowData.map((user) => {
            user.isExpanded = false;
            return (
                    <Fragment key={user.id}>
                        <tr key={user.id}>
                            <td><button type='button' onClick={()=>handleClick(user,props.reportData)}>+</button>{user.id}</td>
                            <td>{user.name}</td>
                        </tr>
                         {!!user.children && <SubRow rowData={user.children} />}
                    </Fragment>
                  )
                
             });

        return (
            <Fragment>{appData}</Fragment>
        )
}
    
 export default SubRow
```

Here is codesandbox implementation [Nested table](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-tereshkova-frib2)

I do not want to use any external packages for same. Please help

**Adding conditional expand collapse scenario**

I want to make expand conditional based on array i am maintaining

Lets say i have an array splits [a,b,c], if value set to this array first level row will have data related to A now whenever use clicks on B, i will make an AJAX request with row-data of A and display rows of B with expand icon as this will be 3 level tree table, similarly whenever user clicks on C i will send data of b and retrieve  data of C. now D will not have any further expand as array size is 3, whenever user adds 4th element in array i have to saw expand icon on C.

Attemp 1:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, Fragment } from "react";
import _ from 'lodash';
import axios from "axios";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getChildren} from '@src/redux/actions/reports';

class TableRowData extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showIcon: false,
    selection: [],
    data: []
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((res) => {
          const rowData = res.data.map((row) => {
              row.isExpanded = false;
              return row;
          });
          this.setState({ data: rowData });
    });

  }

  render() {
    const updateState = (id, itemAttributes) => {
      var index = this.state.data.findIndex((x) => x.id === id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.setState({
          data: [
            ...this.state.data.slice(0, index),
            Object.assign({}, this.state.data[index], itemAttributes),
            ...this.state.data.slice(index + 1)
          ]
        });
      }
    };

    const expandRow = (row) => {
      const index = _(this.state.data)
        .thru(function(coll) {
            return _.union(coll, _.map(coll, 'children') || []);
        })
        .flattenDeep()
        .findIndex({ id: row.id });


       if (index !== -1) {
        let prevState = [...this.state.data];
        let el = _(prevState)
          .thru(function(coll) {
              return _.union(coll, _.map(coll, 'children') || []);
          })
          .flattenDeep()
          .find({ id: row.id });
        el.children = [
          { id: '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5), name: row.id+"_ID1", isExpanded:false,parentId:row.id },
          { id: '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5), name: row.id+"_ID2ß",isExpanded:false,parentId:row.id },
        ];
        el.isExpanded=true;
        this.setState({data:[...this.state.data],prevState},()=>{})
      }
    };

    const collapseRow = (user) => {
      delete user.children
    //  updateState(user.id, { children: {id:1,name:'JANAK'} });
      updateState(user.id, { isExpanded: false });
    };

    const ExpandableTableRow = ({rows}) => {
      //console.log(rows);
      if (rows) {
          return rows.map((row) => {
          let children = null;

            return (
                <Fragment key={row.id}>
                  <tr key={row.id}>
                  <td>
                      <ExpandCollapsToggle row={row} /> {row.id}
                  </td>
                    <td>{row.name}</td>
                </tr>
                  <ExpandableTableRow rows={row.children} />
              </Fragment>
            )
           }
        );

        } else {
          return null;
        }
    };

    const ExpandCollapsToggle = ({row,actions}) => {
        if(row.isExpanded === true) {
              return (<button type="button" onClick={() => collapseRow(row)}>-</button>)
          } else {
              return (<button type="button" onClick={() => expandRow(row)}>+</button>)
          }
    }

    if (this.state.data) {
        return (
          <Fragment>
              <ExpandableTableRow rows={this.state.data} />
          </Fragment>
        );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {"data":state.reportReducer.data};
//  return state;
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getChildren})(TableRowData);
```

Comment: what is your question? what doesn't work now?

Comment: Nested table works but i would like to implement it for multiple levels using one component only,
Sorry for bad explanation You can check codesandbox click on any parent node once child rows are there i want that child row clickable and also should render their child under clicked row

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more, What I understand from your question is that you want to use  expandrow() function from TableRowData.js in your SubRow.js?

Comment: @PadminiS Hi it's not like that exactly 
I want to create nested table using single component based on some conditions
whenevery user clicks on expand button, i will make API call and render rows below expanded button row, it should be work for n-level there are no restrictions on expand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution 1

```js
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import "./style.css";

function ExpandableRow({
  loadData = new Promise(resolve => resolve([])),
  onExpand,
  columns,
  id,
  row
  }) {
  /* added condition to test if not first render
   * if yes then added data through reference which
   * will update the state but because state is
   * updated directly render would not occur
   * to handle this issue `onExpand` function
   * is passed from parent to child which will update
   * state with new data which will intern cause rendering
   */
  const [rowState, setRowState] = useState(1);
  const didMount = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (didMount.current) {
      if (row.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
        delete row["children"];
        onExpand("remove", id, row);
      } else {
        setRowState(2);
        loadData(id, row).then(data => {
          row['children'] = data;
          onExpand("add", id, row);
          setRowState(3);
        });
      }
    } else didMount.current = true;
  }, [rowState]);

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            setRowState(rowState == 3 ? 1 : 3);
          }}
        >
          {rowState == 2 ? "o" : rowState == 3 ? '-' : "+"}
        </button>
      </td>

      {columns.map((column, idx) => (
        <td key={idx}>{row[column]}</td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
}

// function for recursively creating table rows
function ExpandableRowTable({ loadData, onExpand, columns, rows }) {
  return rows.map((row, idx) => {
    const actions = {
      loadData,
      onExpand
    };

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ExpandableRow
          id={idx}
          columns={columns}
          row={row}
          {...actions}
        />
        {row.children && (
          <ExpandableRowTable
            columns={columns}
            rows={row.children}
            {...actions}
          />
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  });
}

function apiData() {
  return axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
  .then((res) => {
    return res.data;
  });
}

let count = 0;
const columns = ["id", "name"];
export default function App() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    apiData().then((data) => {
      count = data.length;
      setRows(data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th />
            {columns.map((c, idx) => (
              <th key={idx}>{c}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <ExpandableRowTable
            loadData={(id, row) => {
              return new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  resolve([
                    {
                      id: count + 1,
                      name: `- ${row["name"]}`
                    },
                    {
                      id: count + 2,
                      name: `- ${row["name"]}`
                    }
                  ]);
                  count += 2
                }, 1000);
              })
            }}
            onExpand={(action, id, row) => {
              if (action == "remove") {
                count -= 2
              }
              setRows([...rows]);
            }}
            columns={columns}
            rows={rows}
          />
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Solution 1 working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cqc7ee)

#### Solution 2

```
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useRef,
  useState,
  useReducer,
  useEffect
} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./style.css";

const data = {
  rows: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "leanne graham"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "ervin howell"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "clementine bauch"
    }
  ],
  options: {
    "": null,
    cities: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "delhi"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "pune"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "hyderabad"
      }
    ],
    network: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "unknown"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "known"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "KNOWN"
      }
    ]
  }
};

const initialState = {
  showIcon: false,
  selection: [],
  rows: []
};

const store = createContext(initialState);
const { Provider, Consumer } = store;

const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
    // console.log(state.rows);
    switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD_SELECTION":
        if (state.selection.indexOf(action.payload) == -1) {
          const newState = {...state};
          newState['selection'].push(action.payload);
          return newState;
        }
        return state;
      case "SET_ROWS":
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          rows: action.payload
        });
      case "TOGGLE_ICON":
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          showIcon: !state.showIcon
        });
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }, initialState);

  return (
    <Provider
      value={{
        state,
        dispatch,
        toggleIcon: () => {
          dispatch({
            type: "TOGGLE_ICON"
          });
        },
        addSelection: value => {
          dispatch({
            type: "ADD_SELECTION",
            payload: value
          });
        },
        setRows: rows => {
          dispatch({
            type: "SET_ROWS",
            payload: rows
          });
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Provider>
  );
};
/*
1 - Loading (o)
2 - Plus    (+)
3 - Minus   (-)
*/
function ExpandableRow({
  showIcon,
  loadData = new Promise(resolve => resolve([])),
  onExpand,
  columns,
  id,
  row
}) {
  /* added condition to test if not first render
   * if yes then added data through reference which
   * will update the state but because state is
   * updated directly render would not occur
   * to handle this issue `onExpand` function
   * is passed from parent to child which will update
   * state with new data which will intern cause rendering
   */
  const [rowState, setRowState] = useState(2);
  const didMount = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (didMount.current) {
      if (row.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
        if (rowState == 2) {
          delete row["children"];
          onExpand("remove", id, row);
        }
      } else {
        setRowState(1);
        didMount.current = false;
        loadData(id, row).then(_data => {
          row["children"] = _data;
          onExpand("add", id, row);
          setRowState(3);
        });
      }
    } else didMount.current = true;
  }, [rowState]);

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>
        {showIcon && (
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              setRowState(rowState == 3 ? 2 : 3);
            }}
          >
            {rowState == 1 ? "o" : rowState == 3 ? "-" : "+"}
          </button>
        )}
      </td>

      {columns.map((column, idx) => (
        <td key={idx}>{row[column]}</td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
}

// function for recursively creating table rows
function ExpandableRowTable({ showIcon, loadData, onExpand, columns, rows }) {
  return rows.map((row, idx) => {
    const actions = {
      loadData,
      onExpand
    };

    return (
      <React.Fragment key={idx}>
        <ExpandableRow
          id={idx}
          showIcon={showIcon}
          columns={columns}
          row={row}
          {...actions}
        />
        {row.children && (
          <ExpandableRowTable
            showIcon={showIcon}
            columns={columns}
            rows={row.children}
            {...actions}
          />
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  });
}

function apiData(requestData) {
  console.log(requestData);
  return axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(res => {
    return res.data;
  });
}

const columns = ["id", "name"];
function Select(props) {
  const { state, toggleIcon, addSelection } = useContext(store);
  const { selection } = state;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{selection.join(", ")}</div>
      <select
        value={""}
        onChange={evt => {
          selection[selection.length - 1] != evt.target.value && toggleIcon();
          addSelection(evt.target.value);
        }}
      >
        {Object.keys(data.options).map((c, idx) => (
          <option key={idx}>{c}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

function Table(props) {
  const { state, toggleIcon, setRows } = useContext(store);
  const { rows, selection } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    // apiData().then((data) => {
    setRows(data.rows);
    // })
    // .catch(err => {
    //   console.log(err);
    // })
  }, []);

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th />
          {columns.map((c, idx) => (
            <th key={idx}>{c}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <ExpandableRowTable
          showIcon={state.showIcon}
          loadData={(id, row) => {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
              const lastSelection = selection[selection.length - 1];
              setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(data.options[lastSelection]);
              }, 1000);
            });
          }}
          onExpand={(action, id, row) => {
            setRows(rows);
            toggleIcon();
          }}
          columns={columns}
          rows={rows}
        />
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <StateProvider>
        <Select />
        <Table />
      </StateProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Solution 2 working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-m9uusf)

#### Solution 3

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, Fragment } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class TableRowData extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showIcon: false,
    selection: [],
    data: []
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((res) => {
      const rowData = res.data.map((row) => {
        row.isExpanded = false;
        return row;
      });
      this.setState({ data: rowData });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const updateState = () => {
      this.setState(
        {
          data: [...this.state.data]
        },
        () => {}
      )
    }

    const ExpandableTableRow = ({ rows }) => {
      const expandRow = (row) => {
          row.children = [
            {
              id: "_" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5),
              name: row.id + "_ID1",
              isExpanded: false,
              parentId: row.id
            },
            {
              id: "_" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5),
              name: row.id + "_ID2ß",
              isExpanded: false,
              parentId: row.id
            }
          ];
          row.isExpanded = true;
          updateState();
      };

      const collapseRow = (row) => {
        delete row.children;
        row.isExpanded = false;
        updateState();
      };

      const ExpandCollapsToggle = ({ row, expandRow, collapseRow }) => {
        return (
          <button type="button" onClick={() => row.isExpanded ? collapseRow(row) : expandRow(row)}>
            {row.isExpanded ? '-' : '+'}
          </button>
        );
      };

      if (rows) {
        return rows.map((row) => {
          let children = null;
          return (
            <Fragment key={row.id}>
              <tr key={row.id}>
                <td>
                  <ExpandCollapsToggle
                    row={row}
                    expandRow={expandRow}
                    collapseRow={collapseRow}
                  />{" "}
                  {row.id}
                </td>
                <td>{row.name}</td>
              </tr>
              <ExpandableTableRow rows={row.children} />
            </Fragment>
          );
        });
        return null;
    };

    if (this.state.data) {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <ExpandableTableRow rows={this.state.data} />
        </Fragment>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { data: state.reportReducer.data };
};
export default TableRowData;
```

Solution 3 working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-neagk3)

Comment: Can you please add some explanation ? is this going to work with axios call as well ?

Comment: @JanakPrajapati yes it will work with axios i just removed axios because i don't want to wait for data each and every time while developing the code.

Comment: @JanakPrajapati i have updated my answer and included api calls for data

Comment: @JanakPrajapati can you share angular project in which you have create the same functionality

Comment: thats company project but i can demonstrate by uploading youtube video will do it in while thanks for responding

Comment: Here is link https://youtu.be/PNTQcCahtog 
As you can see split by option is the one which user will select, i allow user to add more splits in video its city & network, whenever city is added i check at first level that my split array has another entry or not if yes than i enable expand icon, same goes for network. so my table will render like campaign->city->network
there are no restrictions for split options, if there is only one i will not show expand icon.@Chandan

Comment: @JanakPrajapati  from you explanation it seems different functionality or do you want same functionality as in your angular project.

Comment: yeah its kind of same! why do you think it is different
may be i did not explained it properly in question?

Comment: @JanakPrajapati i have add another solution please check.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to replicate same with my scenario tomorrow, code is bit complicated to understand for me but guess i will sort it out !

Comment: As i said default split will be only campid in case assume hydrabad in yours! so until user select next option expand icon should not be visible! and if its like hydrabad,pune than hydrabad rows will be expandable and data of pune will be fetched under hydrabad! let me try i'll figure it out else let you know

Comment: @JanakPrajapati its now almost same as your angular project, it may require tweak for you exact requirement.

Comment: Yeah, will figure it out

Comment: Hi @chandan: i would like to continue with simple class based solution 
Just need little help i am not able to pass children recursively in my component, inspired by your solution i tried to achieve basic functionality using react 
Here is class based component solution it works till 3 level only, if you can help me to figure out it'll be great, may be little tweak is required but i am out of my mind :(
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-dust-0479m

Comment: @JanakPrajapati please can you create you example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: sorry i just checked may be my code is not saved! let me do it

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-paper-lizyg try this link, i think i have not used recursive component properly or as i do not know much about it 
Also the way i add childs inside parent i think its not mutable please check

Comment: @JanakPrajapati check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-pasteur-p3xbf) i have modified your code little bit.

Comment: i don't see what are the changes but i guess this work fine even with lazy load, do you think this one is better solution or i should try bit more? and updating state, was it correct way? i am going to integrate redux-react with it soon ! and also those conditions where expand button should be there or not

Comment: what was my mistake @chandan

Comment: i just used the fact that object are passed by reference so there is no need to find row then add children to it we can directly add children through the reference which is much faster.

Comment: function created were only working for 1 level properly after 2 level collapse function was not working properly i think it was not properly recursive

Comment: that i know but if you see expansion working for two level, but not third

Comment: what did i missed I don't know, your and mine code look bit same yes there are some changes but still did understand

Comment: @JanakPrajapati the problem with you code was that it was not going inside it was only working on 1 level it does not contain anything that move it to level 2 or in other words it was not recursively moving through children it was only working with level 1 data

Comment: thanks, i am implementing expand based on split let's see having bit difficulties but let me try out will update solution once done

Comment: as you was using `this.state.data` `thru` and then finding children and union them but it was never moving to 2 level it was just working on level 1 and same for collapse row

Comment: @JanakPrajapati great let me know once done how much performance it gives or if code is more readable any benefit.

Comment: do you know how solution that recursively parse our data array ?
I want to update properties of childrens if available using single function only using array map, first i want to update parent property if parent have children, recursive function will be called and row of childs will update something like that

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-cookies-0qv38 have look at this, can you help me with recursive remove functioanlity 
i want respective nodes to be removed when some one remove split 
i tried lot but no success
there are buttons on click of that split will be added according to order that user defined 
for ex default is campid , lets click on name and os than tree will be like campid->name->os now lets remove name by clicking on name again at this time all nodes under name  along with name should be removed and parent expand icon should be set accordingly please help

Comment: i tried hard but i am not able to do it recursivly

Comment: @JanakPrajapati sorry i am little busy will check when free.

Comment: have look at problem whenever you get time :)

Comment: @JanakPrajapati I have created a function to recursively delete children [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p2bpnc) check if it fulfil your requirements.

Comment: no, i have achieved that solutions
have look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66397465/how-to-remove-children-objects-recursively-from-object . it has better explanation